# How to sort arrays in a structure by value

Tags: c++, sorting, structure

I want to sort the students by their scores, and print the students who's score is the highest to the lowest.
How can I sort the arrays in a structure by their values?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct students {
    string name[20];
    int number;
    double score;
};

int main()
{
    struct students stu[20];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        cout<<"Please enter the name of the student.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].name;
        cout<<"Please enter the student number.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].number;
        cout<<"Please enter the score.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].score;
    }

}
```

Comment: `string name[20];` should be `string name;`

Comment: Can you use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: To sort your students define a less than operator `bool operator<(const Student& x, const Student& y) { ... }` to give the order you require. Then use `std::sort`.

Comment: `students` should be named `student` since it's only meant to contain info about _one_ student. The `name` array is a mistake, right? It's the `stu` array you want sorted.

Comment: Writing `struct` in front of struct types is a "C-ism" – you don't need it. In C++, struct names live in the regular namespace.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this task using std::sort.

1. adding a operator < () to struct student

```
struct student {
    string name;
    int number;
    double score = 0;
    bool operator < (const student& other) const {
        return this->score < other.score;
    }
};
// Then just simply use std::sort
std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu));
```

2. If you can not modify struct student, then you can define a stand along compare function

```
// define a function that compare students by score:
bool compareScore (const student& a, const student& b) {
    return a.score < b.score;
}

// then use std::sort with the compare function 
std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu), compareScore);
```

3. You can also use a functor to do the work

```
struct studentFunctor {
    bool operator()(const student& a, const student& b) {
        return a.score < b.score;
    }
};

// then use std::sort with the functor 
std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu), studentFunctor());
```

4. Using C++11 lambda, which is the preferred way to do sorting

```
std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu),
          [](const student& a, const student& b){return a.score < b.score;})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `student::number` is supposed to be unique, this is how you can sort it in three different ways.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end
#include <tuple>     // std::tie

// using namespace std; // bad habit

struct student {      // renamed since it contains info about one student only
    std::string name; // not an array of strings
    int number;
    double score;
};

int main()
{
    using std::cin, std::cout;
    student stu[20]; // struct not needed. student is typedef automatically in C++
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        cout<<"Please enter the name of the student.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].name;
        cout<<"Please enter the student number.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].number;
        cout<<"Please enter the score.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].score;
    }

    // three comparison lambdas
    auto cmp_score = [](const student&a , const student& b) {
        return std::tie(a.score, a.number) < std::tie(b.score, b.number);
    };
    auto cmp_number = [](const student&a , const student& b) {
        return a.number < b.number;
    };
    auto cmp_name = [](const student&a , const student& b) {
        return std::tie(a.name, a.number) < std::tie(b.name, b.number);
    };

    // three ways to sort:
    std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu), cmp_score);
    std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu), cmp_number);
    std::sort(std::begin(stu), std::end(stu), cmp_name);
}
```